# Create missing point of a rectangle from right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry

Assume you have 3 connected vertices, which form a right-angled triangle. Is there any easy way to fill in the 4th point to make it a square? I usually copy the corresponding coordinates, when the triangle is axis aligned. But that is a rather slow workflow.

Comment: You could duplicate the triangle, flip it around by scaling it by -1, and then use snapping to position it... and then remove doubles.  You would end up with a square made out of 2 triangles, which you can change to one face by selecting both and dissolving faces.

Comment: You should activate the F2 addon (called 'Mesh F2' and should be standard in 2.8). See for instance https://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/20/f2-modeling-add-on-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit mode script.**

[image]

- Select face in face select mode and run script.
- Finds longest edge (hypotenuse) doesn't test for right angle.
- Creates a new vertex at location of other vert.
- Rotates it 180 degrees about the hypotenuse.
- Creates a new face from new vert and hypotenuse edge.
- Uncomment (remove `#`) from `#bmesh.ops.dissolve_edges(bm,
  edges=[le])` to dissolve the hypotenuse edge, if you want the
  resultant quad.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import pi

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

f = bm.select_history.active
if isinstance(f, bmesh.types.BMFace) and len(f.verts) == 3:
    # longest edge
    le = sorted(f.edges, key=lambda e: e.calc_length()).pop()
    v = (set(f.verts) - set(le.verts)).pop()
    nv = bm.verts.new(v.co)
    bmesh.ops.rotate(bm,
            cent=le.verts[0].co,
            matrix=Matrix.Rotation(pi, 3, le.verts[0].co - le.verts[1].co),
            verts = [nv],
            )
    bm.faces.new([nv] + le.verts[:]).select = True
    #bmesh.ops.dissolve_edges(bm, edges=[le])
    bm.normal_update()
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: I think you win the sledgehammer prize for this one! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats quite awesome!

Answer (score 1):

With pivot set to 3D cursor, in Edit Mode, assuming the triangle is lying in the XY plane:

1. With the hypotenuse selected :  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to selected'
2. With all selected : <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

.. and then, with all selected, Removing Doubles in 2.79 / Merging by Proximity in 2.8, and <kbd>F</kbd> to merge the faces.